# Couchbase Sync-Gateway Multiple Clients

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'am currently playing around with the Couchbase Sync-Gateway and have built a demo app.

What is the intended behavior if a user logs in with the same username on a different device (which has an empty database) or if he deleted the local database?

I'am expecting that all the data from the server should get synced back to the clients.
Is this correct?

My problem is that if i'am deleting the database or login from a different device, nothing will get synced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out and it's exactly how i thought it would be.
If i log in from a different device i get all the data synced automatically.

My problem was the missing sync function. I thought it will use a default and route all documents to the public channel automatically.
I'am now using the following simple sync-function:

```
"sync": `function (doc, oldDoc) {
  channel('!');
  access('demo@example.com', '*');
}`
```

This will simply route all documents to the public channel and grant my demo-user access to it.
I think this shouldn't be used in production but it's a good starting point for playing around.

Now everything is working fine.

Edit: I've now found the missing info:
https://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/current/configuration-properties.html#databases-this_db-sync

> If you don't supply a sync function, Sync Gateway uses the following default sync function
> ...
> The channels property is an array of strings that contains the names of the channels to which the document belongs. If you do not include a channels property in a document, the document does not appear in any channels.